# Getting access to touchesBegan/Moved/Ended to a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm curious to understand exactly what kind of hacking would need to take place in order to be able to handle additional gestures on a UITableViewCell using the touches* API. I'd like to add additional functionality to my UITableView by giving the capability to say call upon a selector based on a swipe from left to right. Perhaps a different selector for a swipe from right to left. Straight forward using the touches API, but how does one go ahead and do something similar with a UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hitTest method in your UIView to get the details of touches and interpret them as gestures in any way you want.
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

The UITableViewCell also uses the left-to-right swipe for editing actions, so you could use those events that already exist if they meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I would try implementing the touchesBegan, touchesEnded delegate methods in my view controller and logging which get called.

I think they do get called but haven't test it.